# Adding email address from Gmail to Contacts

Tags: contacts, gmail

Suppose I have a contact in **Contacts** named John Smith. John's email address is *jsmith@gmail.com*. I've emailed him in the past, but I've never  added his email to his contact details. Now, suppose I compose an email to John, then as soon as I type *js*, **Gmail** guesses that I want to email John and his full email address pops up for me. At this point, I'd like to copy his email address and add it to his contact details in **Contacts**.

Any way for me to do that easily?

I'm using ICS on the galaxy nexus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to copy the email address. Gmail pulls it from an auto-created contact (with only one value). **Merge** this contact with the contact you created manually.

**Procedure:** Using stock contacts app, Select the contact in which you want to insert email. Tap `Edit` from menu. On Edit contact screen, tap `Join` from menu and choose email address contact.

Comment: tip: to view the "auto-created contacts", you may have to change the `contacts to display` setting in contacts to `display all contacts`.

Comment: @Isaac Isn't this set by default? You would have changed it to "Display Contacts having Phone Number" in past.

Comment: @ Sachin: my phone was set to display only "My Contacts" by default.